# How can I construct $\mathbb{S}^1$ in Homotopy Type Theory via pushouts?

Tags: homotopy-theory, homotopy-type-theory

Suppose I take the $0$-skeleton $X_0$ to have a single inhabitant $base$.

Let $S_1$ have a single point $base'$, with attaching map 
$f(base', -)=base$.
If I construct the pushout to the 1-skeleton $X_1$, as below,
$$
\require{AMScd}
\begin{CD}
S_1 \times \mathbb{S}^0 @>{f}>> X_0;\\
@VVV @VVV \\
\mathbf{1} @>>> X_1;
\end{CD}
$$
I end up with $X_1$ defined by

- $inl: \mathbf{1} \rightarrow X_1$
- $inr: X_0 \rightarrow X_1 $
- for each $c:S_1 \times \mathbb{S}^0$, a path $inl(\star) = inr(base)$

This is the interval type though! Where have I gone wrong in my construction?

Answer (score 2):

Nothing wrong in your construction. You don't get the interval since there is no way even to prove that your two paths are equal. For clarity, note that $\mathbb{S}^1$ as a pushout is simply the pushout of the following span

$$
\begin{CD}
\mathbb{S^0} @>>> \mathbf{1} \\
@VVV \\
\mathbf{1}
\end{CD}
$$,
where $\mathbf{1}$ is the unit type and $\mathbb{S}^0$ is the type of booleans (or the coproduct $\mathbf{1}\coprod\mathbf{1}$ if you wish).

Comment: Thanks!  My mistake was that I thought $\mathbb{S}^0$ was a singleton, rather than having two inhabitants.

Comment: How would I construct the interval from a pushout then?

Comment: @Dr.JohnAZoidberg The interval is equivalent to $1$, so it's not clear that that's a meaningful question. For instance, it's a pushout of $1\leftarrow 1\to 1$...

Comment: @Dr.JohnAZoidberg, you are welcome!

Answer (score 0):

I don't see why you say this is the interval type. There are two points in $S_0\times \mathbb{S}^0$, so you get to paths between the two given points, which is indeed a way of describing the circle.

Comment: Is it possible to prove the equivalence of a circle defined by two points and two paths , and the circle defined by $base$ and $loop$?

Comment: @Dr.JohnAZoidberg, yes it is possible and I will be happy to give further details if you open a new question since it is not convenient to answer questions in the comments section.